# (Altland-Simon) Deriving ferromagnetic interaction term from interacting tight-binding Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian

Below is a part of the book "Condensed Matter Field Theory" by Altland and Simon.

[image]

[image]

My question is about deriving the equation with red arrow. This is outlined in the exercise in the figure, but I don't understand the meaning of 
$$\sigma_{\alpha\beta}\cdot\sigma_{\gamma\delta}=2\delta_{\alpha\delta}\delta_{\beta\gamma}-\delta_{\alpha\beta}\delta_{\gamma\delta}$$
Deos $\sigma_{\alpha\beta}$ means Pauli matrix? Then why it has two subindices?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ is the row and $\beta$ is the column. Both range from one to two. The dot product also implicitly sums over the index that tells you which of the three Pauli matrices you're dealing with.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks! Then I understand the meaning of the equation, but how can I derive it (without brute-force way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $\vec{\sigma}_{\alpha\beta}\cdot \vec{\sigma}_{\gamma\delta} = 2\delta_{\alpha\delta}\delta_{\beta\gamma}-\delta_{\alpha\beta}\delta_{\gamma\delta}$ (which I will prove later), we have (switching for convenience the index labels $\sigma \rightarrow \alpha$ and $\sigma' \rightarrow \beta$)

\begin{align}
a_{i\alpha}^\dagger a_{j\beta}^\dagger a_{i\beta}a_{j\alpha}
&=
-a_{i\alpha}^\dagger a_{i\beta} a_{j\beta}^\dagger a_{j\alpha}\\
&=
-a_{i\alpha}^\dagger a_{i\beta} a_{j\gamma}^\dagger a_{j\delta}
\delta_{\alpha\delta}\delta_{\beta\gamma}\\
&=
-\frac{1}{2}
a_{i\alpha}^\dagger a_{i\beta} a_{j\gamma}^\dagger a_{j\delta}
\left(
\vec{\sigma}_{\alpha\beta}\cdot \vec{\sigma}_{\gamma\delta} + 
\delta_{\alpha\beta}\delta_{\gamma\delta}
\right).
\end{align}

Using $\mathbf{S}_{i;\alpha\beta} = \frac{1}{2}a_{i\alpha}^\dagger a_{i\beta}\vec{\sigma}_{\alpha\beta}$ and $n_i = a_{i\alpha}^\dagger a_{i\alpha}$, the above becomes

\begin{align}
a_{i\alpha}^\dagger a_{j\beta}^\dagger a_{i\beta}a_{j\alpha}
&=
-2
\left(
\mathbf{S}_i \cdot \mathbf{S}_j + \frac{1}{4}
n_i n_j
\right).
\end{align}

Multiplying this equality by $J^F_{ij}\equiv U_{ijji}$ and summing over $i \neq j$, we find

$$H_{x} = -2\sum_{ij}J^F_{ij}\left(
\mathbf{S}_i \cdot \mathbf{S}_j + \frac{1}{4}
n_i n_j
\right),$$

as desired.

A proof of the Pauli matrix identity can be found on Wikipedia, but I reproduce it below for convenience. Recall that the Pauli matrices, coupled with the identity matrix (which I denote $\sigma^0$), comprise a complete basis of the space of $2\times2$ matrices. As such, any matrix $M$ can be written as

$$M = \sum_{k=0}^4 c_k \sigma^k$$

for some coefficients $c_k$. Using the fact that $\mathrm{Tr}(\sigma^i) = 0$ and $\mathrm{Tr}[\sigma^i\sigma^j] = 2\delta_{ij}$ for $i=1,2,3$, one finds $c_0 = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Tr}M$ and $c_i = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Tr}[\sigma^i M]$. We therefore have (switching to index notation for later convenience)

$$M_{\alpha\beta} =  \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Tr}M \delta_{\alpha\beta} + \sum_{i=1}^3\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Tr}[\sigma^i M]\sigma^i_{\alpha\beta}.$$

Writing out the traces in index notation, this becomes

$$M_{\alpha\beta} =  \frac{1}{2}M_{\gamma\gamma} \delta_{\alpha\beta} + \sum_{i=1}^3
\frac{1}{2}\sigma^i_{\gamma\delta}M_{\delta\gamma}\sigma^i_{\alpha\beta}.$$

Rewriting $M_{\alpha\beta} = M_{\delta\gamma}\delta_{\alpha\delta}\delta_{\beta\gamma}$ and $M_{\gamma\gamma} = M_{\delta\gamma}\delta_{\gamma\delta}$ and noting that this equality holds for any matrix $M$, we find

$$\delta_{\alpha\delta}\delta_{\beta\gamma} = \frac{1}{2}\delta_{\alpha\beta}\delta_{\gamma\delta}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{\sigma}_{\alpha\beta}\cdot \vec{\sigma}_{\gamma\delta}.$$

Rearranging this gives the desired Pauli matrix identity.